# add a tooltips on top of barChart when mouse over the legend, dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am learning how to use dc.js to add a count on top of barChart when mouse over a legend.

After some research, I figured out that I have to use .on('renderlet')

```js
var legends = chart.selectAll("g.dc-legend .dc-legend-item");
      
      legends
       .on("mouseover.foo", function(d){
        var layername = d.name;
        var val = '';
        if (layername == 'full scat')
         val = 's_full';
        else if (layername == 'partial scat')
         val = 's_partial';
        else if (layername == 'empty scat')
         val = 's_empty';
        else if (layername == 'partial citrate')
         val = 'c_partial';
        else if (layername == 'empty citrate')
         val = 'c_empty';
        else if (layername == 'full citrate')
         val = 'c_full';
        else if (layername == 'N')
         val = 'n_pax';
        else if (layername == 'Y')
         val = 'y_pax';
        
        var div = "";
        if (/scat/.test(layername))
         div = 'g.sub._0  .stack._2 .barLabel';
        else if (/citrate/.test(layername))
         div = 'g.sub._1  .stack._2 .barLabel';
        else if (/N/.test(layername) ||/Y/.test(layername))
         div = 'g.sub._2  .stack._1 .barLabel';
        
        var text = chart.selectAll(div);

        text.text(function(d){
         return d.data.value[val];
        })
        text.attr("visibility", "visible");
      });
      legends
       .on("mouseout.foo", function(d){
        chart.selectAll('.barLabel').attr("visibility", "hidden");
       });
```

I got the first time mouseover ok, but after I filter the data once, then mouse over. the count would not show up.

Here is a [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/cheanney/9897e97a3a18606ac5b8e7d35c1e3bfa)

Comment: Ah, now I see why you needed to use the composite-grouped bar trick! Grouped stacked bars, very nice! This appears to be working for me: at least, I can filter each of the cohort pie charts and reset them, and numbers still appear over the bars when I hover on the legend. Could you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: It looks the hover over legend to show the count over the bar problem is resolved. Now I have another problem. When I click on the grouped-stacked barChart, it only filter based on timepoints. How can I filter on other features like (full_scat, empty_scat etc ...)?

Comment: Thanks for asking this as a separate question, that's the right approach for SO. I'll take a look when I can!